# Jetpack compose TextField soft keyboard obscures text entry

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When initially clicking the text field the whole view correctly shifts upwards so the keyboard is just below text entry.

[image]

After pressing return on the keyboard nothing on the screen moves and it leaves the cursor under the keyboard out of vision.

I had some other TextField issues that were solve by using the [accompanist library](https://github.com/google/accompanist). There is currently an assigned issue for it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192043120). Here is the composable for the textField:

```
@Composable
fun EditTextContent(
    label: String,
    text: String,
    isError: Boolean,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    singleLine: Boolean,
    inputType: KeyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
    onTextChanged: (String) -> Unit
) {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = modifier.navigationBarsWithImePadding().testTag(label),
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            onTextChanged(it)
        },
        label = { Text(label) },
        singleLine = singleLine,
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = { focusManager.clearFocus() }),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = inputType),
        isError = isError,
        trailingIcon = {
            if (isError) {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_warning),
                    modifier = Modifier.size(25.dp),
                    contentDescription = null
                )
            } else {
                null
            }
        },
    )
}
```

Activity in the manifest is set to `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` since adjustResize does nothing for some reason. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think `adjustPan` would not work somewhere after API 24. Also, if it is already marked as an issue, then you should just wait for it to be fixed by Google. What can any of us do for that?

Comment: Well since the accompanist library fixes most of the problems I was after any kind of work around. I've been waiting on google to fix this for a while so that's why i decided to look for work around.